Cannot install packages from oracular-backports
I use Kubuntu 24.10 Minimal,
I was trying to get the libreoffice backport from oracular-backports by inputting the following command:
sudo apt-get install -t oracular-backports libreoffice

However, doing so resulted in the following error:
E: The value 'oracular-backports' is invalid for APT::Default-Release as such a release is not available in the sources

I followed this article, specifically the second option of manually installing backports, I even made sure my release name was oracular by inputting the following:
lsb_release -cs

sure enough, the output was oracular, have I done something wrong?
EDIT: Someone suggested to add the contents of cat /etc/apt/sources.list /etc/apt/sources.list.d/* | grep -v '^#', so here it goes:
deb [signed-by=/etc/apt/keyrings/packages.mozilla.org.asc] https://packages.mozilla.org/apt mozilla main
Types: deb
URIs: http://archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu
Suites: oracular oracular-updates oracular-backports
Components: main universe restricted multiverse
Signed-By: /usr/share/keyrings/ubuntu-archive-keyring.gpg

Types: deb
URIs: http://security.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/
Suites: oracular-security
Components: main universe restricted multiverse
Signed-By: /usr/share/keyrings/ubuntu-archive-keyring.gpg
deb [signed-by=/usr/share/keyrings/waydroid.gpg] https://repo.waydro.id/ oracular main

Looking at it, I might have to remove some 3rd party repos

You might want to add the contents of cat /etc/apt/sources.list /etc/apt/sources.list.d/* | grep -v '^#' to your question. That command line will list the non-commented lines of your source definitions.

Probably an obvious question but I must ask, as you're already running Oracular, have you tried a simple:
sudo apt install libreoffice
AFAIK backports are used to install a package not available in your release but made available in a future release. For example, I'm running Noble (24.04) and I want a package that was added later to Oracular (24.10), so I see if it's been made available in Oracular backports.
Btw oracular-backports seems empty atm, see https://packages.ubuntu.com/oracular-backports/allpackages
FYI, I get the same output with your command as it is and I can see a similar output running sudo apt install libreoffice/oracular-backports.
